# DragListener View.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED not received

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

Hope you can help, iam getting bold.

If have a board game with drag and drop. Problem being that sometimes the drag is started but no callbacks are received for Drag.ended or others.

On the rootview i have a DragListener, so i cant figure out how a drag can start, witout callbacks for drag.Ended?

I also put this draglistener on all the individuel fields on the board.

```
dragListener = new DragListener();
binding.getRoot().setOnDragListener(dragListener);


private class DragListener implements View.OnDragListener {

    boolean moveReverted;

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                moveReverted = false;
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                if (v instanceof PieceHolder)
                    ((PieceHolder) v).setIsHighlighted(true);
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                if (v instanceof PieceHolder)
                    ((PieceHolder) v).setIsHighlighted(false);
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                Timber.d("Action dropped: %s", event.getAction());

                if (!(v instanceof PieceHolder)) {
                    return false;
                }

                PieceHolder pieceHolderTo = (PieceHolder) v;
                pieceHolderTo.setIsHighlighted(false);

                Move move = ((PieceHolder) event.getLocalState()).getMove();
                move.to = pieceHolderTo.getPosition();

                if (pieceHolderTo.hasPiece() || !checkAndCalculatePoints(move)) {
                    return false;
                }

                pieceHolderTo.setPiece(move.piece);

                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                if (!event.getResult() && !moveReverted) {
                    moveReverted = true;
                    revertDrag(((PieceHolder) event.getLocalState()).getMove());
                }
            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So i found out why my self.
The drag wanst actually started, though startDrag was called.
The reason being that the time between my GestureDetection called -> startDrag(),
Was so short that it didnt actually begind the drag process, hence startDrag() returned false.

So solution was (soo simple):

before:

```
  startDrag(null, new ImageDragShadowBuilder(pieceView), this, 0)
  Timber.d("Dragging started");
  refreshView();
```

Solution:

```
  if (startDrag(null, new ImageDragShadowBuilder(pieceView), this, 0)) {
  Timber.d("Dragging started");
  refreshView();
  }
```